# Read Input from String Array

Tags: c++

Want to read string input (from array) and save it into different variables. My code:

```
const string myArray[]{"4", "1 - 5", "Text_1", "Text_2", "Text_3"};

//method, which saves 1st item from myArray into line1, 2nd into line2 and the rest into line3
void Parts::saveParts(const string *myArray, int rows) {
    // rows == length of myArray
    istringstream iss(*myArray);
    int id;
    char del;
    if (iss >> id >> del) {
        line = id;
        string rawLine2;
        if (iss >> rawLine2 >> del) {
            this->setLine(rawLine2);
            string text;
            textItems[numberOfRows-2];
            if (iss >> text) {
                // how can I read the rest of myArray? What should I set as 'del'?
                // 'Text_1' should go into 'textItems[0]' and so on
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // here I want to throw an exception, if reading (iss >> id >> del) goes wrong (in case of id is not an integer
    }

}
```

If the code structure itself is correct, can you direct me to completing signed if statement?

Comment: `istringstream iss(*myArray);` is exactly equivalent to `istringstream iss(myArray[0]);`, which I don't think you want. Are you trying to combine your array into a string (where the items are space separated) and then stick that into a stringstream?

Comment: No, I just want to store these information (from myArray) as a member variables for another class.

Comment: Then why not do `int id = std::stoi(myArray[0]); rawLine2 = myArray[1]; //etc...`?

Comment: Why didn't you use `std::array<std::string, 5> myArray;`?  Then you wouldn't have to deal with pointer decay issues.